# Migration Non Autosar project to Autosar

Tags: autosar

I am working on project to developing a Software Component based on a given application. My concern is only Software component, without BSW developing or also ECU integration or anything else.

What is the main aspect that I should worried about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for the swc you would need to know about configuring the RTE (swc-swc or swc-bsw interaction), with a little knowledge on services modules (ComM, COM, OS etc) APIs required for your application.

Answer (score 0):

When we talk about SW-c, first things to be considered is runnables and their periodicity so you need to check your RTE and O.S task configuration.